# Python list or dict?

Tags: python

In python, would the following be considered a list or a dict?

```
temp = [{'lat': 39.7612992, 'lon': -86.1519681},
            {'lat': 39.762241,  'lon': -86.158436 },
            {'lat': 39.7622292, 'lon': -86.1578917}]
```

I have a pandas dataframe that I am trying to convert to look like the above but I am not certain what I should be converting it to.

Comment: this is a `list` of `dictionaries`.

Comment: It's a list. The list has stuff. That stuff happens to be dicts.

Comment: Just ask python `type(temp)` --> `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a list. More precisely, it is a `list` object, containing a sequence of `dict` objects. You can run `type(temp)` to know the type of that object.